# HTML PHP - how to fwrite time and date from form submit?

Tags: php, html

I wanted to display a date and time on cars.txt when the user submit the form.

how can I do that? can someone teach me ?
here is my html :

```
<form action="lol.php" method="get" >

<h1> select cars</h1>
<select>
<option value=honda> honda civic </option>
<option value=toyota> toyota </option>
<option value=mitshubishi > mitshubishi </option>
</select>
</form>
```

here is my lol.php

```
<?php
header("Location: thanksforsubmit.html");
$handle = fopen("cars.txt", "a");
foreach($_GET as $variable => $value) {
fwrite($handle, $variable);
fwrite($handle, "=");
fwrite($handle, $value);
fwrite($handle, "\r\n");
}
fwrite($handle, "\r\n");
fclose($handle);
exit;
?>
```

Comment: Remove `header` from top of your file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also look at this : [**date()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

```
<?php
// REMOVE header()
$handle = fopen("cars.txt", "a");
foreach($_GET as $variable => $value) {
    fwrite($handle, $variable."=".$value."\r\n");  //the simpler way
}
fwrite($handle, " date = ".date('Y-m-d g:i:s a',  strtotime("+8 hours"))."\r\n");
// assuming China's timzone is GMT +8 and you want 12-hour format time 
// according to your comments below 
fclose($handle);
exit;
?>
```

Comment: thanks but the display time is wrong. its seems different timezone? how can i put asia/china timezone? thanks

Comment: Are you running it in localhost?

Comment: are you getting GMT time?

Comment: look at the update again